# How to export data from SQlite to CSV or Excel or just anything?

Tags: java, mysql, export, android-studio-3.0

Doing research on how to export a database from SQLite, I already found the following code but was not able to make it work for me.

**myDbAdapter.java:**

```
public static void exportDB(Context context) {
    String databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(myDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    String inFileName = databasePath;
    try {
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + myDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Export Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public void export(View view){
    helper.exportDB(getApplicationContext());
}

public static void main(String[] args){}
```

When I press the Export Button it says "Export Failed".
Before I added the void main there was an error telling me that it is needed but I have no idea what to put into it.
Additionally I don't think Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is the right way to find the directory since there is no SDCard in my Tablet.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would not use a program to only export data from SQLite, because all decent databases can generate a csv file directly from their command line interface. `sqlite3` can explicitely: `.header on .mode csv .output filename.csv SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can setup any destination for output file by yourself

p.s.This code should not export anything. It just rewrite the same data.

Comment: Well that makes sense haha thanks.
How do you export it then?

Comment: in case of sqlite cli:
sqlite> 
.header on
.mode csv
.output filename.csv
SELECT * FROM table;
.quit

in case of java use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563008/converting-sqlite-database-to-csv